# All permutations of an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, permutation

I have an array. I want to generate all permutations from that array, including single element, repeated element, change the order, etc. For example, say I have this array:

```
arr = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

And if I use the `itertools` module by doing this:

```
from itertools import permutations
perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(['A','B','C'])]
print(perms)
```

Or using loop like this:

```
def permutations(head, tail=''):
if len(head) == 0:
    print(tail)
else:
    for i in range(len(head)):
        permutations(head[:i] + head[i+1:], tail + head[i])
        
arr= ['A', 'B', 'C']
permutations(arr)
```

I only get:

```
['ABC', 'ACB', 'BAC', 'BCA', 'CAB', 'CBA']
```

But what I want is:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 
 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'BB', 'BA', 'BC', 'CA', 'CB', 'CC', 
 'AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'ACA', 'ACC', 'BBB', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'BAC', 'CCC', 'CAA', 'CCA'.]
```

The result is all permutations from the array given. Since the array is 3 element and all the element can be repetitive, so it generates 3^3 (27) ways. I know there must be a way to do this but I can't quite get the logic right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generator that would generate all sequences as you describe (which has infinite length if you would try to exhaust it):

```
from itertools import product


def sequence(xs):
    n = 1
    while True:
        yield from (product(xs, repeat=n))
        n += 1


# example use: print first 100 elements from the sequence
s = sequence('ABC')
for _ in range(100):
    print(next(s))
```

Output:

```
('A',)
('B',)
('C',)
('A', 'A')
('A', 'B')
('A', 'C')
('B', 'A')
('B', 'B')
('B', 'C')
('C', 'A')
('C', 'B')
('C', 'C')
('A', 'A', 'A')
('A', 'A', 'B')
('A', 'A', 'C')
('A', 'B', 'A')
...
```

Of course, if you don't want tuples, but strings, just replace the `next(s)` with `''.join(next(s))`, i.e.:

```
    print(''.join(next(s)))
```

If you don't want the sequences to exceed the length of the original collection:

```
from itertools import product


def sequence(xs):
    n = 1
    while n <= len(xs):
        yield from (product(xs, repeat=n))
        n += 1


for element in sequence('ABC'):
    print(''.join(element))
```

Of course, in that limited case, this will do as well:

```
from itertools import product

xs = 'ABC'
for s in (''.join(x) for n in range(len(xs)) for x in product(xs, repeat=n+1)):
    print(s)
```

Edit: In the comments, OP asked for an explanation of the `yield from (product(xs, repeat=n))` part.

`product()` is a function in `itertools` that generates the cartesian product of iterables, which is a fancy way to say that you get all possible combinations of elements from the first iterable, with elements from the second etc.

Play around with it a bit to get a better feel for it, but for example:

```
list(product([1, 2], [3, 4])) == [(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

If you take the product of an iterable with itself, the same happens, for example:

```
list(product('AB', 'AB')) == [('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'B')]
```

Note that I keep calling `product()` with `list()` around it here, that's because `product()` returns a generator and passing the generator to `list()` exhausts the generator into a list, for printing.

The final step with `product()` is that you can also give it an optional `repeat` argument, which tells `product()` to do the same thing, but just repeat the iterable a certain number of times. For example:

```
list(product('AB', repeat=2)) == [('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'B')]
```

So, you can see how calling `product(xs, repeat=n)` will generate all the sequences you're after, if you start at `n=1` and keep exhausting it for ever greater `n`.

Finally, `yield from` is a way to yield results from another generator one at a time in your own generator. For example, `yield from some_gen` is the same as:

```
for x in some_gen:
    yield x
```

So, `yield from (product(xs, repeat=n))` is the same as:

```
for p in (product(xs, repeat=n)):
    yield p
```

Comment: Hi, could you please explain to me this line `yield from (product(xs, repeat=n))` I'm a little bit lose in there. Thanks